# Visual Studio 2015 crash when open any file in editor

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2015

I have some problem with VS2015: when I open any project and try to open a file for editing - VS2015 crashes. I try reinstall, all /commands and more.

ActivityLog.xml:

```
  <entry>
    <record>430</record>
    <time>2015/11/03 14:46:35.669</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.IO.FileFormatException: Input file or data stream does not conform to the expected file format specification. ---&gt; System.IO.FileFormatException: Input file or data stream does not conform to the expected file format specification.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Native.Util.ConvertHresultToException(Int32 hr)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Font.CreateFontFace()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Font.AddFontFaceToCache()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.Text.TextInterface.Font.GetFontFace()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.GlyphTypeface..ctor(Font font)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.FontFace.PhysicalFontFamily.GetGlyphTypeface(FontStyle style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.FontFace.PhysicalFontFamily.MS.Internal.FontFace.IFontFamily.GetTypefaceMetrics(FontStyle style, FontWeight weight, FontStretch stretch)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.Typeface.ConstructCachedTypeface()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.Typeface.get_CachedTypeface()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.Typeface.get_Symbol()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextStore.FetchTextRun(Int32 cpFetch)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextStore.FetchLSRun(Int32 lscpFetch, TextFormattingMode textFormattingMode, Boolean isSideways, Plsrun&amp; plsrun, Int32&amp; lsrunOffset, Int32&amp; lsrunLength)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.LineServicesCallbacks.FetchRunRedefined(IntPtr pols, Int32 lscpFetch, Int32 fIsStyle, IntPtr pstyle, Char* pwchTextBuffer, Int32 cchTextBuffer, Int32&amp; fIsBufferUsed, Char*&amp; pwchText, Int32&amp; cchText, Int32&amp; fIsHidden, LsChp&amp; lschp, IntPtr&amp; lsplsrun)&#x000D;&#x000A;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextMetrics.FullTextLine.FormatLine(FullTextState fullText, Int32 cpFirst, Int32 lineLength, Int32 formatWidth, Int32 finiteFormatWidth, Int32 paragraphWidth, LineFlags lineFlags, FormattedTextSymbols collapsingSymbol)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLineInternal(TextSource textSource, Int32 firstCharIndex, Int32 lineLength, Double paragraphWidth, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak previousLineBreak, TextRunCache textRunCache)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at MS.Internal.TextFormatting.TextFormatterImp.FormatLine(TextSource textSource, Int32 firstCharIndex, Double paragraphWidth, TextParagraphProperties paragraphProperties, TextLineBreak previousLineBreak)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.LineEnumerator.FormatLine(TextSource textSource, Int32 textSourcePosition, Double maxLineLength, TextParagraphProperties paraProps, TextLineBreak lineBreak)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.LineEnumerator.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.DrawAndCalculateMetrics(DrawingContext dc, Point drawingOffset, Boolean getBlackBoxMetrics)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Windows.Media.FormattedText.get_Metrics()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTaggerProvider.TextFormatCache.UpdateTextHeight()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTaggerProvider.TextFormatCache.EnsureInitialized()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTaggerProvider.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTagger.GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.&lt;GetTagsForBuffer&gt;d__38.MoveNext()</description>
  </entry>
```

I found a problem. CodeLens broken. If I turn it off, then it works. How i can fix CodeLens? a problem in the font (ActivityLog.txt show some methods with font)?

Comment: Is there unusual about your solution? Fonts, plugins, dll, extensions, ...? It could be anything. Maybe you could also share something about the project itself: is it web-based or WPF, WinForms, ... ? Be more specific in general.

Comment: I found a problem. CodeLens broken. If I turn it off, then it works. How i can fix CodeLens? a problem in the font (ActivityLog.txt show some methods with font)?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a CodeLens. I started checking the registry errors by CCleaner and fix all mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem.Use wpf program, if you install an illegal font, use the font error, when we select font using the property box,every font will be used, so an error occurs.

I found the problem in the environment:

- win7 32(x86)
- .net4.5
- wpf

Hope someone can completely solve.

Comment: this does not answer the question at all